# CrossGeolocator iOS Issue: Either just use events or your own delegate

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, geolocation, delegates

I've been trying to fix this issue for two days now.

This is a Xamarin.Forms application. The Android side is working perfectly. On the iOS, however, I keept geeting this error.

I have a single button in the center of my screen. When it's clicked, it uses the CrossLocator class to get the Geolocation of the phone. However, this problem keeps ocurring:

**Erro: Evento registration is overwriting existing delegate, Either just use events or your own delegate:Plugin.Geolocator.GeolocationSingle-UpdateDelegateCoreLocation.CLLocationManager+_CLLocationManagerDelegate**

Here's my code:

`public static async Task<Tuple<Position, string>> GetLocalizacao()
{
var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;

```
        try
        {
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
            var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new Tuple<Position, string>(null, $"Erro: {ex.Message}");
        }

        var localizacaoFinal = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000));
        return new Tuple<Position, string>(localizacaoFinal, "");
    }`
```

The exception happens when it hits "GetPositionAsync". From there on, I don't know what to do, nor how to actually identify the issue itself.

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images

Comment: My apologies. I edited the post.

Comment: This could be caused by the version of xamarin forms.Please refer to this thread:https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin/issues/322

Comment: I checked that thread but the version they asked to use is way too old compared to the one I'm using now. I'm currently using 5.0.0.2337. Downgrading to 4.5.3 generates a bunch of new issues :/

Comment: Have U add keys in your Info.plist for NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in order to access the device’s location?https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/GettingStarted.html

Comment: I have, yes. But this problem keeps happening :(

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles upon this post, I've been stuck with this issue since I posted it. Still can't get it to work in these conditions. The only way my app worked was downgrading all packages I needed for this.

In order for it to work, it now has:

Xam.Plugin.Geolocator, version 4.5.0.6
Xamarin.Forms, version 5.0.0.2012
Xamarin Essentials, version 1.6.1
Plugin.Permissions, version 6.0.1